# Shall I remove "Remove Ads" and "Restore" buttons after purchasing the items

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7

I implemented an In-App-Purchase code for removing ads after purchasing the item. Do I remove the buttons `Remove Ads` and `Restore`? Or should I keep those buttons? And when I click `Remove Ads` button, it displays an alert like `Do you want to buy one remove ads for 55`? I do not want to display the purchase cast. Can I change the alert text? Please give suggestions for these questions.

Comment: What code have you tried.

Comment: by using store kit framework

Comment: I need a sample of the code that you have tried.

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/introduction-to-in-app-purchases-in-ios-6-tutorial.

Comment: Please add additional information to your question as edit of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the "remove" button and keep the "restore" one as this one is required by Apple. No you can't change the alert text, people must know how much they're paying.